# Magento product rediret issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, redirect

I have recently changed our Magento 1.8 store to including category path in product URL to excluding.

We now have some 404 error issues. I am not sure if its related or a seperate issue altogether...

We have recently cleaned up some of our discontinued product by removing the products from all categories and changing 'catalog,search' to just 'catalog'. We have also included an out of stock message on these pages.

Previously (before turning off catalog path product URLs) we would have the below url.

www.website.com/t-shirts/mens-black-t-shirt.html

Now when we have removed this product from its associated category this URL is giving 404 error in our Google webmaster dashboard

**This URL works**
www.website.com/mens-black-t-shirt.html

If we add the product back to 't-shirts' category and then visit the URL including the category path then it does not return 404 error any more. Shouldn't magento be redirecting when a product is removed from category?

We have always had selected **Create Permanent Redirect for URLs if URL Key Changed > Yes**

Any help appreciated on this.

Thanks

Comment: have you cleared you `cache` and `temp table` like `log_url`?

Answer (score 0):

Problem will probably solved if you re-index `catalog_url (Catalog URL Rewrites)`

If you still face problem then run following MySQL query to the database you are using for your magento store.
`TRUNCATE table core_url_rewrite;`
 When you are done with above query. Do re-index `catalog_url (Catalog URL Rewrites)`.

I'm sure problem will be resolved.
[Reason:- when you unassigned your item from the category, a record of the url `www.website.com/t-shirts/mens-black-t-shirt.html` presents in the table `core_url_rewrite` so either re-index or delete record manually]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I still don't quite understand... 

Google will have indexed the below path

www.website.com/t-shirts/mens-black-t-shirt.html

If we remove the product from this category then magento should automatically redirect to the below?

www.website.com/mens-black-t-shirt.html